# How to copy and paste "ONLY VALUES" from one workbook to another?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Can someone teach me how to copy and paste "ONLY VALUES" from one workbook to another?

The workbook contains about 20 worksheets, and I don't want to copy and paste each sheet one after another into the new workbook.

Comment: Are you looking for a method to select all 20 worksheets at once so that you can `paste special- values only`? Or are you simple unaware how to use `paste special- values only`?

Comment: Check the macros provided in this answer : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623971/copy-data-from-one-workbook-to-another][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623971/copy-data-from-one-workbook-to-another

Comment: yeah, the first option, want to select all 20 sheets and paste special values only unto another workbook

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub CopyPasteSpecVal_1()

  Selection.Copy
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _ 
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your answer is incomplete. The code you provided pastes the copied data back over itself. This is not what the OP requested. Please edit your answer. Thank you for joining the community!

Comment: It does answer the question. Select all the sheets in the workbook and apply the macro. it special paste values only

Comment: The OP is asking how to paste values *from one worksheet to another*. As-is, your code pastes whatever data might be selected back *over* the original selection.

Comment: I get what you mean now. I think one can rename the workbook, then apply the macro.